# How to show these two problems have equivalent solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

I have two problems, where $A$ is positive definite:

$$\inf \{ x^TAx + b^Tx : 1-x^Tx \ge 0,\ x \in \mathbb R^n\} \ (1)$$

and

$$ max_\lambda \ q(\lambda) = -0.25b^T(A+\lambda I)^{-1}b - \lambda : \lambda \ge0 \ (2)$$

and I want to show that the solutions to (1) and (2) are the same.

What I have tried:

- Used spectral decomposition to find the inverse of $(A+\lambda I)$ to understand the behavior of (2)
- Given that, I think that the solution is at the border of the unit ball, so that  $x^Tx = 1$ but I am having trouble expressing this.
- My approach is to solve (2) and then prove that it is also the solution of (1)

Comment: You seem to be suggesting that $x^*=\lambda^*$, but this is not the case. They are, however, *duals* of each other. See m.a.'s solution below. It is not necessarily the case, by the way, that the solution $x^*$ is at the border of the unit ball. In fact, if $b=0$ and $A$ is positive definite, the solution is $x^*=0$.

Comment: More generally: let $x=-\tfrac{1}{2}A^{-1}b$. If $\|x\|\leq 1$, then this is an optimal solution of (1), and $\lambda=0$ is the optimal solution of (2).

Comment: @MichaelGrant Right, but we can't say that $||x|| \le 1$

Comment: For certain values of $(A,b)$, you certainly can. For instance, take any positive definite $A$, and $b=0$. So it is not always the case that the solution is on the border.

Comment: @MichaelGrant to your first comment, I meant they are duals of each other, sorry if it seemed that I meant $x^* = \lambda^*$. I see your point about the unit ball.

Do you agree with m.a. that Slater's condition holds and proves strong duality (this is really all I want to prove, regardless of my original submission)? I am just looking this up now and it seems almost too simple.

Comment: Slater absolutely holds, because the primal problem is strictly feasible. The primal and dual have the same objective value, yes.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Okay thanks. By chance could you point me to anywhere that shows the proof of Slater's condition? Nothing's coming up immediately for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in (1) is convex (since $\mathbf{A}$ is positive definite). 
It is also strictly feasible, since any x such that $\|x\| < 1$ is a (strictly) feasible solution. 
By Slater's condition strong duality holds and the optimal value of (1) will be equal to the optimum of its dual.

The Lagrangian of (1) is
$$
 L(x, \lambda) = x^{T}\mathbf{A}x + b^{T}x - \lambda (1-x^{T}x)
= x^{T}(\mathbf{A}+\lambda \mathbf{I})x + b^{T}x - \lambda.
$$
By the (stationarity) KKT condition, we know that the optimal $x$, $x^{\star}$,
must satisfy 
$$
2 \cdot (\mathbf{A}+\lambda \mathbf{I})x^{\star} + b = 0
$$
and hence, 
$$
x^{\star} = -\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{A}+\lambda \mathbf{I})^{-1}b.
$$
Substituting $x^{\star}$ into the Lagrangian, it is straightforward to verify that $(2)$ is the dual of (1), and according to the above, the optimal value for the two problems is equal.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't need to go past the part about Slater's Condition (which is new to me). The actual problem I'm solving is to show strong duality of the primal (1), and so I wrote out the dual so that I could frame the question in a manner that someone who wasn't familiar with duality may be able to help out with.

I'm a little weary of how simple it is to prove Slater's Condition but if it holds, it holds. So this would still be the case is A is PSD, since the problem in (1) is still convex, right?

Comment: If $\mathbf{A}$ is PSD (i.e., not strictly positive definite), then the only problem is that $\mathbf{A}+\lambda \mathbf{I}$ is not necessarily invertible. In particular, for $\lambda=0$ it is not, although for all other values of $\lambda$ it is.